# Extbase validation skipped on nested form with circular relationship

Tags: typo3, extbase

I'm trying to create a nested form with CMS 8.7.9, to allow IRRE in the frontend.
Submitting this form, i am seeing validation of submitted form-data skipped, if a record in an 1:n relation exists that points back to the root-object.

I have a domain model like this:

```
class RootObject extends AbstractEntity {
   /**
    * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\Child>
    * @cascade remove
    */
   protected $children = null;

   /**
    * @var \Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\OtherObject
    * @validate NotEmpty
    */
   protected $otherProperty = null;
   ...
}
class Child extends AbstractEntity {
   /**
    * @var \Vendor\Ext\Domain\Model\RootObject
    */
   protected $parent = null;

   /**
    * @var string
    */
   protected $title = '';
   ...
}
```

TCA config as created by the ExtensionBuilder, `inline` for the 1:n relation, `passthrough` on the child, pointing to the rootObject.

It should be possible to create and edit a `RootObject` and its children in a single form. My fluid template looks like:

```
<f:form method="post" controller="RootController" action="update" name="rootObject object="{rootObject}">
    <f:form.select property="otherProperty"/>
    <f:for each="{rootObject.children}" as="child iteration="iter">
            <f:form.textfield type="text" property="children.{iter.index}.title"/>
    </f:for>
    ...
</f:form>
```

When I submit this form for a `RootObject` without a `Child` the NotEmpty validation for the `$otherProperty` is correctly evaluated and I get the corresponding validation error. But as soon as a `RootObject` has a `Child` in the relation, the validation of the `otherProperty` is not evaluated.

I tracked this down to the `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Validation\Validator\GenericObjectValidator`, where `validate` resets the result of the validation.

I don't fully understand why - but when validating the `rootObject` extbase calls the validator of the `Child`, that in turn calls validation of `rootObject` again *reusing the validator instance* that is currently validating the `rootObject` further up the call-tree. It then overwrites the current `$result`.

Patching that line with

```
- $this->result = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Result();
+ $this->result = $this->result ?: new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Error\Result();
```

fixes the problem.

Am I using the nested form wrong, or is this an Extbase bug?

**Edit:**
Some more insights about the call-tree of the validation:
`ConjunctionValidator($rootObject)` calls
`GenericObjectValidator($rootObject->children)` calls
`CollectionValidator($rootObject->children)` calls
`ConjunctionValidator($child)` calls
`GenericObjectValidator($child->parent)` calls
the same instance of `ConjunctionValidator` as we started with. That leads to overriding the validation results generated before descending into validating `$rootObject->children`.

Answer (score 0):

Try in your controller to do something like below:

```
public function initializeUpdateAction()
{
    if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('rootObject')) {
        $this->arguments->getArgument('rootObject')
            ->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()
            ->forProperty('children.*')
            ->skipProperties('parent');
    }
}
```

The initialize action is run before your action and before validation.

First we check to see if we have the argument. Then we get the property mapping configuration for the argument `rootObject` and tells it not to validate `children.*.parent` since it´s already validated.

It´s untested and written from memory but hope it helps you out.

Comment: I didn't knew about skipProperties, looks promising - thanks!.
But the path notation and wildcard matching does not work there.
Using `$this->arguments->getArgument('rootObject')->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->getConfigurationFor('children')` I can get the configuration for the ObjectStorage. Accessing the children would be possible if I knew their indices - found no solution to iterate over all `$subConfigurationForProperty`. So all I need is somehow to descend into the ObjectStorage.

Comment: Found a way by iterating over keys of `$this->request->getArguments()['rootObject']['children']`. But when debugging I found that there is not even a mapping done for `parent` as that field does not exist in the form. So the error has to sit somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry. `skipProperties` expects property names, not a property path. I have updated my answer above with `forProperty` which does accept an path with wildcards. [See implementation on github here](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/v8.7.9/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Property/PropertyMappingConfiguration.php#L382)

Comment: I just realized that you use `passthrough` in your TCA configuration for field `parent`. Personally i don´t use the extension builder and I have never used `passthrough` on a field that I would map to a domain model. I think you have to provide the correct `group` or `select` TCA configuration for the `parent` field to get extbase to work as expected. A quick way to test if this is the field introducing the issue is simply to temporary remove it from the model, flush the cache and then test your form again. If it now validates correct then you know where your issue is.

Comment: Sorry for the silence - had to lay this aside for a while.
Thanks for your further comments. `passthrough` is not the culprit, already tried with select. But the extension-builder is using `passthrough` thats why i thought it would be the less errorprone setting.
Actually it validates correct as long as I don't have the `parent` field in the `child`. As soon as thats in there, validation gets overridden.

Comment: As far as I can see the Problem with the Wildcard for property mapping configuration is, that there arealready more specific entries for children.0, .1 etc that are user in favor of the wildcard setting. But otoh i found no way to enumerate all the children there to explicitly set all validators. Any idea on that?